# Write a sequence of tuples to a csv file f#

Tags: f#, tuples, export-to-csv

Iam trying to write a sequence of tuples to a csv, but the normal File.WriteAllLines is overloaded by a sequence of tuples.

I have tried therefore to flatten my tuples into a sequence of strings.

Here is my code:-

```
open System;;
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection;;

let tupleToString (t: string * float) = 
        if FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) 
        then String.Format("{0},{1}", fst t, snd t)
        else "";;

    let testTuple = ("monkey", 15.168);;

    tupleToString(testTuple);;

let testSeqTuple = [("monkey", 15.168); ("donkey", 12.980)];;

let allIsStrings (t:seq<string * float>) = Seq.collect tupleToString t;;

allIsStrings(testSeqTuple);;
```

When I use "tupleToString" on just one tuple the results are just fine.

However the Seq.collect part of allIsStrings returns the tuples broken down by characters.

I have also tried Seq.choose and Seq.fold, but these simply throw errors.

Can anyone advise as to what function from the sequence module I should be using - or advise on an alternative to File.WriteAllLines that would work on a tuple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `Seq.map` to convert all elements of a list to `string` and then `Array.ofSeq` to get an array which you can pass to `WriteAllLines`:

```
let allIsStrings (t:seq<string * float>) = 
  t |> Seq.map tupleToString
    |> Array.ofSeq
```

Also, in your `tupleToString` function, you do not need to use reflection to check that the argument is a tuple. It will always be a tuple, because this is guaranteed by the type system. So you can just write:

```
let tupleToString (t: string * float) = 
  String.Format("{0},{1}", fst t, snd t)
```

You *could* use reflection if you wanted to make this work for tuples with arbitrary number of parameters (but that is a more advanced topic). The following gets elements of the tuple, converts them all to string and then concatenates them using a comma:

```
let tupleToString t = 
  if FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) then
    FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(t)
    |> Array.map string
    |> String.concat ", "
  else failwith "not a tuple!"

// This works with tuples that have any number of elements
tupleToString (1,2,"hi")
tupleToString (1.14,2.24)

// But you can also call it with non-tuple and it fails
tupleToString (new System.Random())
```

Comment: Awesome. Quicker than greased lightning.

Comment: Thanks for the added info, yes, I have over typed the input really.

Comment: Wow, lots of extra info added. You deserve extra credit :) The more advanced bits will come in useful later as the tuples start to contain more information and types.

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines` has an overload that takes `seq<string>`, so the `Array.ofSeq` is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @ildjarn Good point! I guess that has been added after .NET 2.0 or something like that?

Comment: Yep, added in .NET 4.0 (I forgot to check before commenting). I guess your approach makes for a better answer since it's backwards compatible. :-]

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is much better, but I've written this now, so there.

```
let testSeqTuple = [("monkey", 15.168); ("donkey", 12.980)]

let tupleToString t = String.Format("{0},{1}", fst t, snd t)
let tuplesToStrings t = Array.ofSeq (Seq.map tupleToString t)

for s in tuplesToStrings(testSeqTuple) do
    printfn "s=#%s" s
```

Comment: I'll upvote you dude.  It's hard to compete with Tomas for speed and good answers :-)